# Why do I have a stackoverflow problem with a microcontroller?

Tags: assembly, stack-overflow, microcontroller, pic

I will explain the problem I'm programming in assembly and using the pic 16f84a, I'm in the topic about table management and jumps, I have to show a letter on a display, the character is a constant that I defined for example the letter 'P', so I think my program should work, but when I simulate it in Proteus, it gives me a stack overflow problem, but if I use an auxiliary memory space and save the letter in it, the program works right, so I can't understand why I need an auxiliary memory space to save the letter that I had already declared before and which I assume is already stored in a memory space, I also have to say that since it is a constant I am not modifying it, I am only using it to do a subtraction.

```
;THIS CODE PRESENTS THE STACK OVERFLOW PROBLEM
;CONFIG ZONE
          __CONFIG  _CP_OFF &  _WDT_OFF & _PWRTE_ON & _XT_OSC
          LIST      P=16F84A
          INCLUDE   <P16F84A.INC>
         
Character EQU       'P'                 ;DECLARATE AND SAVE THE LETTER 'P' AS A CONSTANST
;CODING ZONE
          ORG       0      
          
Start
          bsf       STATUS, RP0         ;MOVE TO BANK 1           
          clrf      PORTB               ;DECLARATE PORTB AS OUTPUT    
          bcf       STATUS, RP0         ;MOVE TO BANK 0
          
Main
          movlw     'A'                 ;MOVE THE LETTER 'A' TO W REGISTER
          subwf     Character, W        ;REMANDEIR THE HEXADECIMAL VALUE OF 'P' AND 'A', AND SAVE IT IN THE W REGISTER
          call      LetterTo7Segments   ;CALL A SUBROUTINE   
          movwf     PORTB               ;SHOW THE VALUE OF THE LETTER IN DISPLAY          
          goto      Main
          
LetterTo7Segments          
          addwf     PCL,F               ;ADD THE VALUE OF THE REGISTER W TO PROGRAM COUNTER, TO JUMP TO ONE OF THE INSTRUCTIONS
                                        ;AND RETURN THE HEXADECIMAL VALUE INSIDE THE W REGISTER
          DT        77h, 7Ch, 39h, 5Eh, 79h, 71h, 6Fh, 76h, 19h, 1Eh, 7Ah, 38h, 37h
          DT        54h, 3Fh, 73h, 67h, 50h, 6Dh, 78h, 1Ch, 3Eh, 1Dh, 70h, 6Eh, 49h
          END
```

```
;THIS CODE WORKS RIGHT
;CONFIG ZONE
          __CONFIG  _CP_OFF &  _WDT_OFF & _PWRTE_ON & _XT_OSC
          LIST      P=16F84A
          INCLUDE   <P16F84A.INC>
         
Character EQU       'P'                 ;DECLARATE AND SAVE THE LETTER 'P' AS A CONSTANST
Aux       EQU       0x0D                ;DECLARATE A SPACE OF MEMORY
;CODING ZONE
          ORG       0      
          
Start
          bsf       STATUS, RP0         ;MOVE TO BANK 1                    
          clrf      PORTB               ;DECLARATE PORTB AS OUTPUT          
          bcf       STATUS, RP0         ;MOVE TO BANK 0
          
Main
          movlw     Character           ;MOVE THE VALUE OF THE CHARACTER TO W REGISTER
          movwf     Aux                 ;SAVE THE VALUE OF W(LETTER) INSIDE THE SPACE OF MEMORY CALLED AUX
          movlw     'A'                 ;MOVE THE LETTER 'A' TO W REGISTER
          subwf     Aux, W              ;REMANDEIR THE HEXADECIMAL VALUE OF AUX(LETTER) AND 'A', AND SAVE IT IN THE W REGISTER
          call      LetterTo7Segments   ;CALL A SUBROUTINE      
          movwf     PORTB               ;SHOW THE VALUE OF THE LETTER IN DISPLAY           
          goto      Main
          
LetterTo7Segments          
          addwf     PCL,F               ;ADD THE VALUE OF THE REGISTER W TO PROGRAM COUNTER, TO JUMP TO ONE OF THE INSTRUCTIONS
                                        ;AND RETURN THE HEXADECIMAL VALUE INSIDE THE W REGISTER
          DT        77h, 7Ch, 39h, 5Eh, 79h, 71h, 6Fh, 76h, 19h, 1Eh, 7Ah, 38h, 37h
          DT        54h, 3Fh, 73h, 67h, 50h, 6Dh, 78h, 1Ch, 3Eh, 1Dh, 70h, 6Eh, 49h
          END
```

So why do I need the memory space called Aux?, thanks for your answers.

Comment: "Aux EQU 0x0D" just gives the hex value 0x0D a name. it's not allocating space anywhere

Comment: what looks suspicious to me is your usage of "LetterTo7Segments". the value you compute the first code is most probably way beyond the range of your jump table

Answer (score 3):

When you subtracting...

```
  movlw     'A'                 ;MOVE THE LETTER 'A' TO W REGISTER
  subwf     Character, W        ;REMANDEIR THE HEXADECIMAL VALUE OF 'P' AND 'A',
```

... the result is negative and point outside of your lookup table named **LetterTo7Segments**.

The MPLAB IDE has good software simulator use it to check your code!

Answer (score 1):

```
      subwf     Character, W        ;
```

This means `subtract` `W` from `file`. But you don't declare a `file` with the name `Character`. `Character` is a literal with the value `'P'`. You had to declare a fileregister to work with....As you did in the second solution.